# Netbeans cannot start Tomcat because of port 8080 is busy

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

That's problem: I use Netbeans + installed Tomcat 6 in Ubuntu 12.04. I integrated Tomcat into Netbeans and I can see his in the node "Servers". When I trying to run my application, I get the error - Cannot start Tomcat. Port 8080 is busy (I use Russian version, but the sense is there).

So, question is: how to check what's service does block Tomcat ? Can I stop this service ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get process name and number with following command.

```
netstat -anp | grep 8080
```

you can kill with [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command

Comment: I see the next:

tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      5652/java       
tcp6      68      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:45723         CLOSE_WAIT  -               
tcp6      68      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:46516         CLOSE_WAIT

Does it means that I have to kill Java and tcp 6?

Comment: it means java process with identified by 5652

Comment: Is there a more permanent solution?  I tend to get this same problem alot using Netbeans 7.2, and I would like to not have to go kill the process.

Instead, I want the problem to never happen again.

Comment: I am looking at my history and think that I might have been too harsh in down-voting.  It works but is what someone I know would call a "duct-tape solution".  When really the problem is stupid NetBeans itself.  It occasionally won't kill the Apache Tomcat server when you tell it to and the NetBeans people have yet to fix it!